# Selecting first and last row at the same time in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make a macro to select the first and the last row in my data range but I don't know how to make it so that the selection for both rows stay. This is what I tried to do:

```
Sub Macro6()
'
' Macro6 Macro

    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=15
    Dim lr As Long
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Rows(lr).Select
    Rows(1).Select


End Sub
```

I dont't really need a 'first row' code since my data always starts in Row 1. I should probably mention that I have never learned VBA before, but I'm kinda forced to learn it for work XD (got the above code by Googling). Just wondering if there is a method that will make both selections be highlighted at the same time. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim lr As Long

With Sheets("Sheet1") '~~> change to suit
    lr = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A1," & "A" & lr).EntireRow.Select
End With
```

Or like this:

```
.Range("1:1," & lr & ":" & lr).Select
```

To select non-contiguous ranges, you separate the string address by comma (within the string).

```
Range("A1,A5,A10").Select
```

If you use comma outside the string address:

```
Range("A1", "A5").Select
```

That is the same as:

```
Range("A1:A5").Select
```